# Is there any way to Merge parent column based on Child Column using Python Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a 3 columns Date and Shift as below

```
Date    Shift   Subject
26th    Shift 1 English
26th    Shift 1 Maths
26th    Shift 1 Hindi
26th    Shift 2 Anatomy
26th    Shift 2 Physiology
26th    Shift 3 Earth Science
27th    Shift 1 VHDL
27th    Shift 1 Verilog
27th    Shift 1 Logic Design
27th    Shift 2 Power Electronics
27th    Shift 3 VBA
27th    Shift 4 Sociology
28th    Shift 1 Law1
28th    Shift 2 Law2
```

Please note in the above shift column is dependent of date, subject column is dependent on both date and shift I need a VBA Code to display below output attached in image, in next sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could try to use this code:

```
fila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
For i = 1 To Cells(fila, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 0).Column
    cont = 0
    For j = 1 To fila
        While (Cells(fila - j + 1, i - cont) = "")
            cont = cont + 1
        Wend
        n = Cells(fila - j + 1, i - cont) & " " & n
    Next j
    MsgBox n
    n = ""
Next i
MsgBox "Fin de aplicación"
```

I guess it starts in A1:B1, but select the first cell left top of your table before start the macro. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Show me more information, i put message box but you could use an array